# python websocket 404 on Handshake

Tags: python, websocket

I use python websocket-client to send message to client.

On client side I have:

```
var s = new WebSocket('http://' + location.host + ':8000/ws');
s.onopen = function(e) { 
    $("#connected3").html('open');
    console.log(e)
}
s.onclose = function(e) { 
    $("#connected").html('close') 
}
s.onmessage = function(e) {
    $("#connected2").html(e.data);
}
```

and on server side I have:

```
import websocket
ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws = create_connection("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws", sslopt=  {"check_hostname": False})
```

I get this error:
Handshake status 404

My guess is, there is a problem with web socket server:
ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws

Did I miss something in setting up my web socket?

Full code:
https://github.com/Homa/weatherApp

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a websocket client in your backend. You have to create a websocket server and connect to in your javascript code.

`ip install git+https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server.git` and connect to it.

```
from SimpleWebSocketServer import SimpleWebSocketServer, WebSocket

class SimpleEcho(WebSocket):

    def handleMessage(self):
        # echo message back to client
        self.sendMessage(self.data)

    def handleConnected(self):
        print(self.address, 'connected')

    def handleClose(self):
        print(self.address, 'closed')

server = SimpleWebSocketServer('', 8000, SimpleEcho)
server.serveforever()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Flask-Sockets extension, you have a websocket implementation for gunicorn directly in the extension which make it possible to start with the following command line 
`gunicorn -k flask_sockets.worker --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 app:app`